# How do I add a Google Maps link in ODOO?

Tags: xml, odoo

Hey I have one form so I wanted a google map view in odoo specially in HR Module I will be having address of all employees .So When I click on specific view it should show some view with map

Comment: see this link in odoo app store or  https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/8.0/google_map/

Comment: any free app or please help me to code how can we get view

Comment: this app is free in version 7 and migrate it into version 8.

Comment: it is showing 37 $ and do you know about geoengine

Comment: check this link https://www.odoo.com/apps/modules/7.0/google_map/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to inherit `hr.employee` and use odoo method for google_map is in `res.partner`.

like,

```
class hr_employee(osv.osv):
    _inherit = "hr.employee"

    _columns = {
        'map': fields.function(google_map_img, string='Map', type='text'),
    }
    def google_map_img(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
        employee = self.browse(cr, uid, ids[0], context=context)
        if employee.address_id:
            map_img_url = self.browse(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, ids[0], context=context).address_id.google_map_img()
            return {ids[0]: map_img_url}
        return None
```

here one functional field, that calculate the map data using partner address and return a map url.

using thism field you can easily render map on front-end using `<img t-att-src="map"/>`

but if you want to render it on back-end form view than you have to create a widget that render a image using generated url.`(widget="image")`

in `google_map_img()` method has extra parameter like zoom, height, width. change as per your need.

this two method are use for google map image and map link.

```
def google_map_img(...)
    pass
def google_map_link(...)
    pass
```

search this method in `addons/website/models/website.py`

if you use this methods then add `website` module in depends on your module in `__openerp__.py`

Comment: i have just created a function what you written above

Comment: `google_map_img()` method in `res.partner` so use it with `address_id`, search it in `website.py`. or you have to add `website` in module depends, because is it in website module

Comment: in which module we have website.py

Comment: `addons/website/models/website.py` in `class res_partner`

Comment: no one is `google_map_img` and 2nd `google_map_link`

Comment: i am not able to get it becoz in website.py google_map_imag() one line is there in inherited module of hr in above function also has same funtion and how to replace partner.street etc with hr

Comment: please bro get me solution how can i add it

Comment: if you are avialable can you come on skype i will share my skype id

Comment: or else send me module hr inherited module which u worked with google map shridharivani@gmail.com

Comment: i am getting error   File "/home/newuser/odoo-8.0-14/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0.post20151126-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/alfa_fleet_gmap/fleet.py", line 29, in <module>
    from libxslt import timestamp
ImportError: No module named libxslt